# Counting number of a particular item in a dictionary with a nested list

Tags: python, dictionary, element, counting

I have a dictionary that contains the following multiple values:

```
{'ads': None, 'results': [{'height': 1112, 'image': 'https://www.ucsfhealth.org/-/media/project/ucsf/ucsf-health/medical-tests/hero/coombs-test-direct-2x.jpg', 'source': 'Bing'},{'ads': None, 'results': [{'height': 1132, 'image': 'https://news.images.itv.com/image/file/2164058/img.jpg', 'source': 'Bing'},'ads': None, 'results': [{'height': 1112, 'image': 'http://s1.ibtimes.com/sites/www.ibtimes.com/files/2016/11/11/hiv-test.jpg', 'source': 'Bing'}
```

If I want to simply count how many values of 'image' exists in the dictionary, what's the most efficient way to do that (e.g., in the example above, I want the output to report 3)?

Comment: You seem to have incorrectly copy-pasted your `dict` because right now it contains a syntax error. Please format your dictionary in a human-readable format. Nobody wants to scroll a 2000px wide scroll box...

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to recursively search the dictionary:

```
def count(my_collection, my_key):
    # Start the count
    total = 0
    
    # If it is a list or a tuple, use a different counting method
    if isinstance(my_collection, list) \
            or isinstance(my_collection, tuple):

        for item in my_collection:
            if item == my_key:
                total += 1
            else:
                total += count(item, my_key)

    elif isinstance(my_collection, dict):
        if my_key in my_collection:
            total += 1
        for item in my_collection.values():
            total += count(item, my_key)

    return total


my_dict = {'image': 1, 4: [{'image': 1}, {'not_image': 2, 'a': {'image': 1}}]}
print(count(my_dict, 'image'))
>>> 3
```

The way it works:

- it counts the number of times a key is in your dict/list/tuple
- it checks all the dicts/lists/tuples in that dict/list/tuple
- repeat step 1